# Контроль версий

Tags: git, php, centos

Допустим, у меня скоро появится сайт на котором будут всегда онлайн пользователи. Каким образом мне вносить изменения в сайт чтобы он не ложился при каждой ошибке?

Я думаю что нужно взять копию сайта и с нею работать, а при новой версии как-то обновлять.

Я слышал что-то про git, но даже представления не имею что это, как это работает и как может помочь решить мою задачу.

Интересуют ссылки на какие либо статьи или содержательные ответы.

Answer (score 2):

[Book](http://git-scm.com/book)

> The entire Pro Git book, written by Scott Chacon and published by Apress, is available here. All content is licensed under the Creative Commons Attribution Non Commercial Share Alike 3.0 license.

Answer (score 2):

Достаточно иметь локальную копию и ковырять ее. Проверенный новый функционал заливать на сайт. Мне всегда казалось это разумным и само собой разумеющимся. Если я не правильно вас понял - переформулируйте.

Comment: Правильно. Ваш вариант имеет право на жизнь.

Answer (score 1):

git это [система управления версиями](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0_%D1%83%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%8F%D0%BC%D0%B8)

Используя git вы сможете в любой момент вернуться к любому предыдущему состоянию проекта, посмотреть когда, что и кем было изменено. Если вы работаете над проектом совместно с другими программистами, можно легко объединять свои исходники с изменениями других участников. Но даже работая над проектом в одиночку git очень полезен.

Несколько книг:

- [Book](http://git-scm.com/book/ru)
- [Волшебство Git](http://www-cs-students.stanford.edu/~blynn/gitmagic/intl/ru/)
- [Git How To](http://githowto.com/ru)